# What is' [quote>'?

Tags: zsh

I'm a newbie when it comes to using terminal. I accidentally misspelled clear as c'ear in the terminal and the command line began with [quote> from there on instead of the current directory. Can someone please tell what this is and how to get back to current directory, because googling it didn't get me any answers.[image: Image of the terminal after c'ear]

Comment: Hi, as you opened a single quote, your shell is waiting for the closing one. 2 solutions there, you can press CTRL C to cancel everything or a single quote ' and enter. But this will try to execute everything you typed then. Just to explain a bit more, every time you open either a single or a double quote, you have to close it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works, I'll keep this in mind now.